# Post something in Facebook public group using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I have integrated Facebook sdk with android studio and i can post something on my profile. I want to post something on a public Facebook group. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

To post on Facebook you app need permissions to do that.

> Write Permissions - Apps need separate publish permission to post content on the person's behalf.

To request permission to publish you need add the following permission **publish_actions**. To ask for publish permissions in your app, you can use the **LoginManager**.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(
    fragmentOrActivity,
    Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

Here is the documentation to make a [sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) in Facebook.

But if your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how your app uses it.

**Update:**

About posting on open groups, [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group) says the following:

> You can't publish on this endpoint, however Facebook apps and games can create [new app groups using a different edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/app/groups#publish).

You cant

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/ I have taken help from this link to post on my profile. Now i want to know how to post on a public facebook group

Comment: You have to use [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group) to try this, but if you are not moderator group is not possible post on there.